# Differentiate between bash and sh via Node.js child process

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell

I start a child process with Node.js using `bash` or `sh`, like so:

```
const file = '<some-path>.sh';  
const cp = require('child_process');

//sh
const n = cp.spawn('sh',[file]);

//bash
const n = cp.spawn('bash',[file]);
```

the problem I have am having, is that frequently there will `.sh` files on the filesystem that actually *only interpretable by bash*.

Even though said .sh files have the following hashbang

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

if I explicitly start the process with `sh`, then the script will get executed with `sh` instead of `bash`, and then an error will get raised by `sh`.

For example, the `read -u` command is a bash utility, not sh.

The problem is solved generally in the shell by using the hashbang and running a script like so:

```
./<some-path>.sh
```

however, in Node.js I would have to choose whether to use sh or bash and I won't know beforehand what type of script it is!

Should I enforce a file extension convention of .sh for sh files and .bash for bash scripts?

Or is there a way with Node.js to launch a "lower level kernel process" instead of sh or bash to evaluate the shell script to determine whether to use bash or sh?

Comment: One not-so-elegant solution would be to read the first line of the file using [`fs.readSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position) and check the hashbang.

Comment: yeah, thanks, would like to avoid that. I think the "exec" command will be the one I am looking for after doing some more research, but have to verify that.

Comment: @Kryten the answer I added seems to work

Comment: The only reason it runs "sh" or "bash" is because you explicitly tell it to run "sh" or "bash". There is nothing about `spawn` that suggests, recommends or requires that. You can put literally any executable there, including your script.

Comment: right, thanks, figured that out, I wonder why 'exec' didn't work, I would have thought it would have worked.

Comment: Also, `bash` is a POSIX-compatible shell, just with extensions. Anything you can run with `sh`, you can run with `bash` as well. The reason for sticking to strict POSIX compliance is so your script can run on a machine that does not have `bash`, but some other POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, I thought that the `exec` command is the one I am looking for:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec

but when I use it like so, I get an error.

```
 const n = cp.spawn('exec', ['file.sh']);
```

And the error is as follows:

```
 Error: spawn exec ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

the error originates here:

```
n.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('\n',err.stack || err,'\n');   // here
    });
```

However, this seems to work!

First, make sure the shell script is executable by using:

```
chmod u+x <file.sh>
```

then we can execute like so:

```
const n = cp.spawn('/absolute/path/to/file.sh');
```

This will invoke the correct interpreter determined by the hashbang, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Voila!